# How to extract all text after a matching pattern from pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My dataframe is:

```
     name     type
0    apple    red fruit with red peel that is edible
1    orange   thick peel that is bitter and used dried sometimes
```

I want to extract all text after `peel` from each row and create a separate column

```
     name     type                                              peel
0    apple    red fruit with red peel that is edible            that is edible
1    orange   thick peel is bitter and used dried               is bitter and used dried
```

I am trying this:

```
def get_peel(desc):
    text = desc.split(' ')
    for i,t in enumerate(text):
        if t.lower() == 'peel':
            return text[i:]
    return 'not found'

df['peel'] = df['type'].apply(get_peel)
```

But the result I am getting is:

```
0         not found
1         not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.extract` with regex.

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['apple', 'orange'], 'type': ['red fruit with red peel that is edible', 'thick peel that is bitter and used dried sometimes']})
df['peel'] = df['type'].str.extract(r"(?<=\bpeel\b)(.*)$")
print(df['peel'])
```

**Output:**

```
0                              that is edible
1     that is bitter and used dried sometimes
Name: peel, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

`df` creation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['apple','orange'],
                   'type':['red fruit with red peel that is edible','thick peel that is bitter and used dried sometimes']})
```

Code to add new column:

```
df['peel']=df['type'].replace(regex=True,to_replace=r'.*peel(.*)',value=r'\1')
```